# List View Web Part No border!

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I have a list view web part that Im using with JSLink to view as a ticker feed and the web part zone has a white border around it, which still appears if the web part is minimized so its not the CSS of the ticker!

[image]

How can I remove this white border?

Comment: what does the DOM-Explorer (F12 - Developer-Tools) of the browser tell about this section? There we'll get the info which element and formatting is responsible for. And if we know that we can deviate whether to hide something by settings or by css or by additional csom code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the list view web part the custom web part created by you?

If the list view web part is the default list view web part, you could change to different views and different tool type to check if the same issue will occur.

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you could remove the web part and re-add the web part to check if the same issue will occur.

And then you could use F12 to check the white border.